Derivative of the determinant of a matrix with respect to the components
Given a square matrix $A$
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
    a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn} 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
what is the derivative of its determinant with respect to one of its components? In other words,
$$
\frac{\partial \det(A)}{\partial a_{ij}} = ?
$$
If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$-matrix,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} 
    \end{pmatrix},
$$
I've obtained that
$$
\frac{\partial \det(A)}{\partial a_{ij}}
=  \begin{bmatrix} 
    a_{22} & -a_{21} \\
    -a_{12} & a_{11} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the cofactor matrix of $A$, equivalently, $(A^{-1})^T \times \det(A)$.
Does this result hold for $n>2$? Is $\dfrac{\partial \det(A)}{\partial A} = (A^{-1})^T \times \det(A)$ correct? If not, is there a nice formula to calculate the derivative?

It's always given by a cofactor; this follows from Laplace expansion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) or equivalently from the adjugate formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).

I find the easiest way to do this is computing the directional derivative of the function. Let $$f(A) = \det(A).$$ The directional derivative at $A$ in the direction $B$ is $$D_Bf(A) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|{t=0}f(A+tB) =  \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|{t=0}\det(A+tB). $$ To figure out what this is, first calculate it when $A = I$. Then observe that $\det(A+tB) = (\det(A))\det(I + tA^{-1}B)$. Finally, to answer your question, let $B$ be the matrix such that $B_{ij}=1$ and all the other entries are zero.

A general formula is $D \det(A) (\Delta) = \operatorname{tr} (\operatorname{adj} (A) \Delta )$, in this case, $\Delta = e_i  e_j^T$, and so $D \det(A) (e_i^T e_j) = \operatorname{adj} (A)_{ji}$.

Consider the $3\times3$ case.
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\\ g&h&i\end{vmatrix} =
  a\begin{vmatrix}e&f\\ h&i\end{vmatrix} - b\begin{vmatrix}d&f\\ g&i\end{vmatrix} + c\begin{vmatrix}d&e\\ g&h\end{vmatrix}$$
If you want the partial derivative w.r.t. $a$ (or $b$ or $c$), then the second and third terms vanish and you just get the cofactor corresponding to $a$. In general, you can do the cofactor expansion
$$\det(A)=a_{1j}C_{1j}+a_{2j}C_{2j}+\cdots+a_{ij}C_{ij}+\cdots+a_{nj}C_{nj}$$
Note that none of the $C_{kj}$s have entries from the $j$th column, in particular, they don't have $a_{ij}$, therefore$\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}$
$$\pdv{}{a_{ij}}\det(A)=C_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$$
where $M_{ij}$ is the discriminant of the matrix after removing $i$th row and $j$th column.
Hope this helps. :)
